# Double click listener on JTable in Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, double-click, listselectionlistener

I am curious as to how to call `valueChanged` overridden method only if a row in `JTable` has been double clicked. For now the below code snippet achieves one click action or event arrow key to navigate through a list of people and would adjust `JLabel` accordingly. What I'm trying to do is something similar just like I did for one click, but this time IF and ONLY IF a row has been double clicked `dto` would change else nothing happens. How do I do this :(

```
   class ListDataUI {

    public void addListSelectionListener(ListSelectionListener listSelectionListener) {
            summaryTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(listSelectionListener);

 public T getSelectedDTO() {
        final int selectedRowIndex = summaryTable.getSelectedRow();
        if (selectedRowIndex != -1) {
            return data.get(summaryTable.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRowIndex));
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
        }
    }




    class MainMenu extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private void initListeners() {
    searchTable.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                AcademicDTO dto = (AcademicDTO) searchTable.getSelectedDTO();
                acImgLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon());
                label_name.setText(dto.getTitle() + " " + dto.getForename() + " " + dto.getSurname());
                label_role.setText("Role: " + dto.getRole());
                label_phone.setText("Phone: " + dto.getPhone());
                label_room.setText("Room: " + dto.getRoom());
                label_hours.setText("Hours: " + dto.getHours());
                label_mobile.setText("Mobile: " + dto.getMobile());
                if (dto.getImage() != null) {
                    acImgLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(dto.getImage()));
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

}


 private void initListeners() {
    contactTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            ContactDTO dto = (ContactDTO) contactTable.getSelectedDTO();
            if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                System.out.println(dto.getForename());
            } else {
            }

        }
    });
}
```

not sure of the rest above...

Comment: A MouseListener seems more appropriate.

Comment: yes, but unsure about the adjusting part to get the row

Comment: What is the problem of getting the row? Either is is already selected and you can get it with `JTable.getSelectedRow()` or you use the mouse event point and the method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#rowAtPoint(java.awt.Point)

Answer (score 101):

Try this:

```
mytable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        JTable table =(JTable) mouseEvent.getSource();
        Point point = mouseEvent.getPoint();
        int row = table.rowAtPoint(point);
        if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2 && table.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
            // your valueChanged overridden method 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: should add && row!=-1

Comment: @OfekRon: Explanation is, that the table might have a certain size, but the data inside does not completely and visually fill it out. So if the user clicks outside of the data area but still inside of the table, the return-value of the row is `-1`, which should be handled.

Answer (score 2):

Relocate the code of the event handler into a private method in your host class, then implement the `MouseListener` or extend the `MouseAdapter` then invoke the private method there. The first step (i.e. creating the private method helps you invoke the same logic from multiple event handlers).

Detecting the double click in the `MouseHandler` is made easy by the call to `MouseEvent.getClickCount()`

Comment: see my edit, I am not sure how to call getSelectedDTo only if double clicked

Answer (score -3):

@MooHa Your class ListDataUI should implements MouseListener.