# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (-1) when selecting a row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am attempting to obtain the row number someone has double-clicked in a JTable. The trigger fires, but it doesn't think I've clicked a row. When I retrieve the row number it is always -1:

```
informationTable.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
            int row = informationTable.getSelectedRow();
            System.out.println(row); // always -1
            informationTable.setValueAt('1', row, MEAL_COL); // fails...
        }
    }
});
```

Why is this not giving me the correct row, any row for that matter?

Edit:

To answer how I turned off editing (for specific columns) I overrode the `isCellEditable` method of the DefaultTableModel class as follows:

```
private class KAMDTM extends DefaultTableModel {
    private final boolean[] canEdit = new boolean[] {false, false, false, false, false, false, true};

    public KAMDTM(Object[][] data, String[] cols) {
        super(data, cols);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return canEdit[columnIndex];
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you double click? when I try doing that, it takes me into editing a cell where my mouse is pointed at

Comment: Editing is turned off. Even when I change it to do a single click it fails.

Comment: How do you turn off editing?

Comment: Please post your full code to see how you have turned off the editing?

Comment: K, this works for me, on my table, my Row is never -1, and if you are clicking outside the cells, you will get -1

Comment: I changed it back so that my cells are editable and still get -1 for a row selected.

Comment: Your listener is probably added to a JTable that has not been added to the frame. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. That is create a frame add a table to the frame and then add the listener to the table. The whole code will be about 15 lines of code. Then I'm sure you will find the basic concept works and you will now need to debug you code to find the difference between the working code and your `SSCCE`.

Comment: are you using informationTable.setEnabled(false) to capture the mouse double click event?

Comment: try using selectionListener to select the row of the table. it seems like now row has been selected in the JTable.

Comment: This code works for me, I don't know how come it doesn't work for him, post a picture of your UI

Comment: When I attempted to make an sscce (removing all my other components), it works. I am attempting to find the error now. I'll post my error when I find the solution.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @camickr The listener is probably added to a component that is on the screen (otherwise it wouldn't not trigger), BUT they might not be using a reference to the component which is on the screen. BUT, the solution is still, runnable example

Comment: Instead of using a MouseListener on the JTable, you should use `table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener( ...);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably get answer from this post : [Double click listener on JTable in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852719/double-click-listener-on-jtable-in-java) , look at the second answer the code suggests to use :

```
Point p = evt.getPoint();
int row = table.rowAtPoint(p);
```

Comment: This still does the same thing, there is no change there