# Java Event Calendar Using Netbeans

Tags: java

I 'm Developing a School Database. In that system I want to make an `Event Calendar` using Table. In table, there should be buttons for all the days which can open another form.

Any ideas on how I can do it?

Comment: Cell Renderering but never understood

Comment: Why do you need buttons? You can listen on double-clicks (and other actions) on the table cell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852719/double-click-listener-on-jtable-in-java