# JAVA- Select a cell while Double click on it in Jframe?

Tags: java, jframe

I have a JTable in my JFrame window. JTable has 4 columns. I want to select a cell in  4th column(only 4th column) only when double clicking on it. Is there any way to that? Help..

Comment: Please post some code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: jtable.setCellSelectionEnabled() is false for the whole program. I just want to make it true for a particular cell only when i double click on that particular cell.

Comment: There are **tons** and **tons** of q/a on this site around Jtable and double clicks; like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852719/double-click-listener-on-jtable-in-java ... did you do **any** prior** research?